# Validate user input from console. Are commands valid etc

Tags: java, design-patterns, data-structures, io, console

When a program gets command from console, what is the standard/best practice to verify that the command is valid and execute it?
I was thinking something like a `HashMap<String,Object>` but doesn't this degrade performance with all the string comparisons?

Comment: You might have to clarify what you mean by "valid". Are you comparing the command against a list of commands that you consider valid? And no, proper application of `HashMap` does not automatically degrade performance.

Comment: By `console` you mean command line arguments?

Comment: @Andremoniy:Yes, command line arguments

Comment: @GregHewgill:Yes valid commands but string comparison has a performance overhead (this is irrelevant to actual hashmap)

Comment: You don't even want to *think* about performance at this point. Especially parsing command line options, which is done once when your application starts, and will have absolutely no bearing on your overall application performance.

Comment: @GregHewgill:Misunderstanding.I mean continuous input from the user.Interaction with the user.Not the startup program arguments

Comment: Ok, well it's still interactive with the user. If you spend even 0.01 second parsing the user's input (which is *millions* of machine instructions), the user will never notice the delay.

Comment: @GregHewgill:I am not sure I understand what is your suggestion on this.

Comment: My suggestion is don't worry about performance. Write the code so it works first, *then* adjust for performance if you find that it is unacceptable. In this case, you are unlikely to notice any kind of performance problem.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do not worry about performance. Time for that will come later (or, more probably, will not come at all). Parsing commands will not take more time than executing the commands, will it?

As for processing commands: first of all, you should split the input into atomic tokens. These might be the command itself, switches -a -b -c, or parameter values, which may sometimes be between "".

Once you have split the input into tokens, verify if the command exists. If it does, check if the tokens supplies are valid for the command.

I do not know what kind of architecture you want to use. Sometimes people use one class for one command, sometimes there's one class and a lot of methods, sometimes there's one method with an extremely long case. Which is best for you? Probably not the last one, but whatever you choose should match the complexity of the commands and their jobs.

Example1:

```
abstract class Command {
  public abstract String getName();
  public abstract int execute(String[] parameters); // not implemented in Cmd* below
}

class Cmd1 extends Command {
  public String getName()
  {
    return "Cmd1";
  }
}

class Cmd2 extends Command {
  public String getName()
  {
    return "Cmd2";
  }
}

//somewhere else:
public void execute(String[] params) {
  Command[] commands = {new Cmd1(), new Cmd2()};
  for (Command cmd: commands) {
    if (cmd.getName().equals(params[0]) {
      cmd.execute(params);
      return;
    }
  }
  throw new RuntimeException("unknown command "+params[0]);
}
```

example 2:

```
void processCmd1(String[] params);

void processCmd2(String[] params);


public static final String CMD1 = "cmd1";
public static final String CMD2 = "cmd2";
static HashSet<String> availableCommands = new HashSet<String>();
static {
  availableCommands.put(CMD1);
  availableCommands.put(CMD2);
}


{
  if (availableCommands.contains(params[0])) {
    switch(params[0]) { // java 7
      case CMD1:
        processCmd1(params[0]);
        break;
      case CMD2:
        processCmd2(params[0]);
        break;
    }
  } else {
    throw new RuntimeException("unknown command "+params[0]);
  }
}
```

example 3:

```
abstract class Command {
  public abstract String getName();
  public abstract int execute(String[] parameters); // not implemented in Cmd* below
}

class Cmd1 extends Command {
  public String getName()
  {
    return "Cmd1";
  }
}

class Cmd2 extends Command {
  public String getName()
  {
    return "Cmd2";
  }
}

static HashMap<String,Command> commandMap = new HashMap<String,Command>();
static {
  Command cmd = new Cmd1();
  commandMap.put(cmd.getName(), cmd);
  cmd = new Cmd2();
  commandMap.put(cmd.getName(), cmd);
}

//somewhere else:
public void execute(String[] params) {
  Command cmd = commandMap.get(params[0]);
  if (cmd == null) {
    throw new RuntimeException("unknown command "+params[0]);
  } else {
    cmd.execute(params);
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't stress it enough: it - itself - doesn't matter! You have to consider your entire command processing architecture and THEN decide how you can, in that architecture, check if the command exists. If you do not want to do it, just use `HashSet<String>` and use `contains()`.

Comment: I don't follow you.Can you please provide 2 different examples of architectures that use different ways to verify that a command exist?You can keep it brief if you like

Comment: +1 for the effort.But still in first example you iterate over all possible commands while in the second you confirm existence using a HashSet and the just switch to process it.  
The second is clearly better but in both cases your "bottleneck" is the string comparison. Even in `HashSet` a comparison must be done. I was wondering if there was a "trick"/pattern to avoid it

Comment: @Jim I just added another example. I also thought on an example using reflection on classes and static getters for name, but enough is enough...

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice library for command line arguments processing. It is [Apache commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/introduction.html).

Comment: I am interested in how it is done.Knowing the existing of a library is useful

Comment: There are sources of that library on apache commons site.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Design Pattern for this would be Chain of Responsibility or Interpreter, but Interpreter may be overkill. Chain of Responsibility is basically a way to create an if/then/else decision tree dynamically, rather than having it hardcoded as if/then/else statements.

I would pre-process the input, then use Chain of Responsibility to parse the input.

I am pretty sure that the standard libraries for command line parg processing use a formal grammar that is compiled into running code. At least that's how it was done back in the stone age when I last worked with it (lex and yacc was the popular choices), but today it's probably specialilzed quite a bit.

Comment: Perhaps my question is not put properly. My interest is mainly in the mapping of string arguments to commands as this (the string comparison) would be a bottleneck.Not about a general architecture

Comment: Well Jim, why did you then tag it with design-patterns? That is an architecture tag...

Comment: You can not avoid doing some kind of decoding of the string, no matter what. You will have to translate it, and translating /is/ decoding. The fastest way to translate the string to some kind of jump point is usually some kind of hashing... which is basically what is going on in the HashMap solutions. Writing your own is usually not a good idea except if you are doing some kind of super time critical system... and if that's what you are doing, you probably shouldn't be using Java in the first place. I say "usually". If the list of strings is fixed, a state machine is faster at decoding.

Comment: By state machine I mean: A program that extracts the smallest possible decision tree to convert a string to a jump point char by char. The tree should perhaps not be the smallest possible: You would have to consider both how common cases are, and if you want to decode one faster than others. But this is a very very specific micropotimization...